# Activate a dropdown option from another button/llink

Tags: jquery, select, click, dropdown

I have been struggling to work out how to do this. I have a dropdown on a page that I have no control over code wise -

```
<select name="dex_item" id="dex_item" onchange="dex_updateItem()">
<option value=1>2016</option>
<option value=4>2017</option>
<option value=5>2018</option>
</select>
```

I want to create a simple button/link that when clicked activates one of the options. So for example when I click #click then the option value=4 is selected.

I have seen examples similar but can't get anything to work...

Comment: provide with code that you have tried so that we can help

Comment: which examples? can you post an image or gif ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood but to select a value of the the select input you can use the following code :

```
$("#click").click(function(e) {
  $("#dex_item").val('4');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/fmncst9L/

**EDIT**

If you want to trigger the onchange event you can do this :

```
 $(function() {
   $("#click").click(function(e) {
     var select = $("#dex_item");
     select.val('4').trigger("change");
   });
 })

 function dex_updateItem() {
   alert("change");
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/z2bnvuru/

Comment: @Ish posted this solution.

Answer (score 1):

check this: https://jsfiddle.net/c2yusbka/

On click of button you can set value of select element and the option will be selected accordingly.

```
$('#click').click(function(){ 
   $("#dex_item").val("4");
});
```

```js
$('#click').click(function(){ 
   $("#dex_item").val("4");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dex_item" id="dex_item" onchange="dex_updateItem()">
  <option value=1>2016</option>
  <option value=4>2017</option>
  <option value=5>2018</option>
</select>
<button id="click">Click Here</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `selected` attribute to target `option` using `.prop()`

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $("select > option[value='4']").prop("selected", true);
    $("select").change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dex_item" id="dex_item" onchange="console.log('changed')">
    <option value=1>2016</option>
    <option value=4>2017</option>
    <option value=5>2018</option>
</select>
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It changes the dropdown but doesn't execute as f I had manually changed the dropdown. I assume something to do with the onchange="dex_updateItem()"...?

Comment: @ScottEldo If you want to fire change event, you should use `$("select").change()` See https://jsfiddle.net/8453mufc/